# C: word in array of char

Tags: c, arrays, char, cpu-word

i have this array:

```
char alph[] ={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.',',',':','?','=','-','(',')','"','\'','/','%','@','!'};
```

It's possible to change the symbol ' % ' with a word like 'perc' ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How would 4 characters fit into 1?

Comment: Not unless your platform supports a `char 'perc'`. That is unlikely.

Comment: You need to better define "change". Find and replace in the string? Make equivalent symbol? ect.

Comment: If just to substitute % with perc you can define macros #define perc '%' but use it without quotes in array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the declaration of `alph`, each element is a single `char`, whereas the string `"perc"` consists of multiple characters. Do note, however, that the character literal `'perc'` (with single quotes) *is* valid C code, but its value is generally not useful; if you were to try to print it out, you'd wind up with garbage instead of the word "perc".

If you want to use `"perc"` in your array, then you'll need to change the type of the array to `const char *alph[]`, and change all other elements to use double quotes (i.e. `"A", "B", "C"`, etc).

Comment: Thanks, but if I have an array of pointers to char it will change the result?

Comment: What result? If you're talking about whether you can replace `%` with `perc`, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is replace a *single* `char` by a `multicharacter literal`, which is implementation-dependent. It may work, how these values will be stored is up to compiler, so if you do:

```
char[] a = {'a, 'b', 'c'};
a[0] = '123';
```

and

```
printf("%c", a[0]);
```

isn't going to print `123` like you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

No you may not, but you could replace it with the letter `'p'`...

what you have is a an array of `char` size with 50 elements, chars hold the values -128 through 127
you could store similar data in an array of `char *`'s which would be pointers to memory positions that had null terminated C-strings.

Comment: `char` does not always have to be -128 to 127. It may be 0 to 255, or it may be -2147483647 to 2147483648.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen you are half right, char can be signed or unsigned.

Comment: There's nothing in the C standard that `char` has to be 8 bits. It only says that `sizeof(char)` must evaluate to 1.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen though that is true, as per the _de jure_ reading, practical advice would be to consider 8-bits to be a byte. I don't think C would be a good choice if you were developing for a univac anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out you cannot.

If you however change the definition of `alph` from an array of `char`

```
char alph[] ={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.',',',':','?','=','-','(',')','"','\'','/','%','@','!'};
```

to an array of pointers to `char`

```
char * alph[] ={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",".",",",":","?","=","-","(",")","\"","'","/","%","@","!"};
```

this would be feasable. In this latter case just do:

```
alph[<index of %>] = "perc";
```